# NullReferenceExceptionUnhandled

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, object-reference

I'm writing a blackjack program but my problem is what's the solution when creating an object that has a list of other objects, but when I create the object at first, the list is empty.  I think that's why I'm getting this error.  Below is my code where I initialize a player as having an instance of a hand in the player's constructor but I get the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error message when I call the method playerHand.Hit(card);

```
public class Player
{
    private string name;
    public Hand playerHand;

    public Player()
    { }

    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.playerHand = new Hand();
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public void TakeCard(Card card) 
    { playerHand.Hit(card); }`
```

`

```
public class Hand
{
    public List<Card> hand;
    public Hand()
    {
        hand = new List<Card>();
    }
    public int handValue;`

    public void Hit(Card card)
    {
        hand.Add(card);
    }

    public int HandValue()
    {
        foreach (Card card in hand)
            handValue += (int)card.value;

        return handValue;
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public Game(IEnumerable<string> playerNames)
    {
        List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
        foreach (string name in playerNames)
            players.Add(new Player(name));
        Player dealer = new Dealer();
        players.Add(dealer);
        Deck playingDeck = new Deck();
        Deal(playingDeck, players);
        Play(playingDeck, players);
        DisplayResults(players);
    }       

    public void Deal(Deck deck, List<Player> players)
    {
        deck.Shuffle();
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            foreach (Player player in players)
                player.TakeCard(deck.Deal());                
    }
```

Comment: Where does the debugger say the error is? Where's the Play method?

Answer (score 4):

You have this line:

```
Player dealer = new Dealer();
```

You didn't show us the code for `Dealer`. But, it's obvious from the code that `Dealer : Player`. Note that your default constructor for `Player` never initializes `Player.playerHand`.  If the default constructor for `Dealer` calls the default constructor for `Player` (and it does by default), then `playerHand` will be `null` for `dealer`.

So, my guess is that `playerHand.Hit(card);` is giving you a `NullReferenceException` when invoked for the `dealer` because you never intialized `Player.playerHand`.

To fix it, just provide an initializer

```
public Hand playerHand = new Hand();
```

and remove the corresponding line from the constructor `Player(string)`.

Finally, and this is an *aside*, you have way too many `public` variables in your classes. You're "leaking" variables that consumers of your class can modify without restraint and muck up your invariants. [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) is the name of the game.